# Xcode: Add/Remove contacts type of buttons

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a very simple question to ask. I am making an app where the user is presented with a screen with two text fields
- Name
- Phone Number
When they enter that info I want to store that information in my app. Its kind of like the iphone contacts button/layout. The user enters a new contact and its displayed on a page with all his other entered contacts.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: In this case, you should use a plist. For smaller things, use `NSUserDefaults`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to save username and phone Numbers.

1) [NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058858/should-i-use-nsuserdefaults-or-a-plist-to-store-data)

2) [PList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144670/write-data-to-plist)

3) [SQlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178011/how-to-insert-only-one-username-and-password-in-sqlite-database/8178682#8178682)

4) Server

These are used in the increasing order of contact details data that you want to enter in your application.

first three stores the contact details(name and phone number) in  your application whereas the last one store's the contact details on the server.You have to create connection to the server for sending details to the server or retrieving details from the server.

Comment: thank you coolanilkothari. Those links were and example were perfect!